# I've done breadboards and programming, where is a good place to move on?

Tags: arduino, soldering

I have a decent (equivalent of introductory college level) with circuit design, all on breadboards, as well as programming on a variety of microprocessors and a couple FPGAs. I'm just wondering where would be a good place to go on from here in more advanced and higher level circuit designs, but I'm not sure if I'm at the point where I should make the jump to PCB layouts, or is there an intermediate step that's recommended? I was highly considering making something like Arduino on pcb.

I've also never actually used a soldering gun, and that's something I know I should learn, but I'm not sure really what kind of devices are good to learn that on, and circuits to do stuff like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try transferring the circuits you have been working on to stripboard. That will also get you soldering components. Don't get a soldering gun, BTW, get a temperature-controlled soldering station with suitable tips.

Comment: thanks, I thought I heard of the stripboard stuff before, but I didn't know the exact name. I'll look into getting some of that, some more components, and a station. I'm not sure where to look online for those pieces, I know theres not many brick stores selling components near me, but I don't know good sites either, I've just pretty much gotten a few bags of random stuff for my own projects and borrowed ones from my school's lab for assignments.

Comment: @nocley Some of the popular shops seem to be [SparkFun](http://www.sparkfun.com/), [Farnell](http://www.farnell.com/), [Adafruit](http://adafruit.com/), [Mouser](http://mouser.com) and [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/). There are countless others, but these come to my mind right now.

Answer (score 2):

A great way to learn how to solder is to buy a few electronic project kits ([Quasar Electronics](http://www.quasarelectronics.com/) is a great site), and solder these together. You can also find some good [soldering tutorials](http://www.epemag.wimborne.co.uk/solderfaq.htm) on the internet.

A good intermediate step up from breadboards to PCBs is to use [stripboard](http://www.maplin.co.uk/components/pcb/stripboard) which is a board pre-drilled with a grid of holes and strips of copper you can solder to.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to learn how to solder it to disassemble old electronic devices.

You could try to desolder everything on an old radio or DVD player or something similar. This way, you'll be able to see for yourself how different devices behave when being soldered and what kinds of damage they can take. Also, you may be able to get some broken devices for free, if you're lucky. Plus, you'll get a supply of various components which may or may not be useful.

Comment: Good point and note blow tourch is useful for taking things apart, but not putting them together. http://www.opencircuits.com/Salvage_Parts_and_Sources

Answer (score 1):

Before you begin designing PCB's, you may want to familiarize yourself with a circuit simulation program such as PSPICE.  I would recommend getting PSPICE version 8 (student edition), which you can easily find for free. It's older, but it has an easier-to-learn interface and does everything. From there, you can design a circuit, and then run simulations on it to ensure proper functionality. There are tons of PSPICE tutorials out there and it is commonly used in college electronics courses. Once you've designed a circuit in PSPICE, it can be exported to a PCB layout program.

Comment: I've used PSPICE for simulations, but I didn't know about the PCB export abilities on that. I'll see what I can do with that, but I do need to get a bit more components before I even bother doing PCB stuff.